# Wording of problem 6. (a) in Chapter 3 of Spivak's Calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, predicate-logic

I've been having difficulty understanding this problem for awhile and figured out why. To clear things up, I just need to understand the logical difference ( if there's no difference, then the problem is obviously missing information) between these sentences:

(Find a polynomial function $f_i$ of degree n-1 which is 1 at $x_i$  and 0 at $x_j$ for j $\ne$ i.),

(Find a polynomial function $f_i$ of degree n-1 which is 1 at $x_i$  and 0 at $x_j$, for j $\ne$ i.).

The placement of the comma after $x_j$, how does that differentiate the last sentence from the first?

Comment: The comma makes no difference to the meaning.

Comment: I can't really see any difference or even why/how it would make a difference.

Comment: Makes no difference at all.

Comment: You may be looking at an older version of the textbook. Omitting the hints, my copy (fourth edition) reads:

 6. (a) If $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are distinct numbers, find a polynomial function $f_i$ of degree $n-1$ which is $1$ at $x_i$ and $0$ at $x_j$ for $j \neq i$.

  (b) Now find a polynomial function $f$ of degree $n-1$ such that $f(x_i) = a_i$, where $a_i, \dots, a_n$ are given numbers.

There don't seem to be any duplicated statements.

Comment: I think the sentence would be clearer with a comma after $x_i$ (not $x_j$). That being said, when the actual mathematical content is taken into consideration, it's clear that there can be no difference in meaning between the two sentences. The $i$ is considered fixed since it appears in $f_i$. Only $j$ varies in the phrase "for $j \ne i$."

Comment: I was wondering what $f_i$ denoted as I've never seen that notation before, thanks David.

Comment: Does the notation $f_i$ always symbolize that i is fixed or can it take on different meanings?

Comment: What the author is asking is that you define functions $f_i$ satisfying the required conditions for $i = 1, 2, \dots n$. (I'm guessing the possible values of $i$ here.) That is, find a polynomial $f_1$ satisfying the conditions when $i = 1$, a polynomial $f_2$ when $i = 2$, etc. In each of these cases, the required conditions involve a statement that starts with "for every $j$ not equal to $i$." In defining $f_3$, for example, this means $j \ne 3$. You need $f_3(x_3) = 1, f_3(x_1) = 0, f_3(x_2) = 0, f_3(x_4) = 0, f_3(x_5) = 0, \dots$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me how the significance (or lack of significance)
of the comma is supposed to relate to the meaning (or lack of meaning)
of the sentences.
But here is how I would interpret the statement about the polynomial
function $f_i$:

- There are $n$ numbers of interest to us, $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. No two of these numbers are the same.
- The polynomial function $f_i$ is of degree $n - 1$.
- $f_i(x_i) = 1$.
- For each $j$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, if $j \neq i$ then $f_i(x_j) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up.